# Is it possible to have a Jackson custom deserializer with non-default constructor?

Tags: java, deserialization, jackson

Lets say that I have the following classes:

```
public class Person {

    String name;
    Set<Department> departments;

}

public class Department {

    String code;
    String name;

}
```

So I want to write a custom Department deserializer in order to annotate the deparments field in the Person class to use it. Because this custom deserializer will only be used to deserialize Department objects that are inside a Person object. The problem is that my custom Department deserializer will need to have a DepartmentRepository that must be passed in the deserializer's constructor. How can I do this? Is this possible? I don't want to register the deserializer in the object mapper because it must only be used when the deparatments field from the Person class gets deserialized.

**UPDATE:** What I need is, apart from annotate the departments field with JsonDeserialize annotation with the parameter contentUsing = MyCustomDepartmentDeserializer.class, is a way to tell Jackson that when it creates a MyCustomDepartmentDeserializer object, it must done it by calling a constructor that receives a DepartmentRepository. The deserializer may be something like this:

```
public class MyCustomDepartmentDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Department> {

    private final DepartmentRepository departmentRepository;

    public MyCustomDepartmentDeserializer(DepartmentRepository departmentRepository) {
        this.departmentRepository = departmentRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Department deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        //IMPLEMENTATION!
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

First things first: to specify deserializer to use for contents of an array you can use

```
@JsonDeserialize(contentUsing=MyDeserializer.class)
Set<Department> departments;
```

to specify deserializer to use for contents of the collection in question.

As to ability to use non-default constructors, @JsonCreator allows this.
But to pass a context object, you need Jackson 1.9 may be your friend (see "[Jackson 1.9 overview](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/10/entry_463.html)"), which allows "injection" of objects outside of JSON.
You can then mix and match injectable values and JSON properties, for example:

```
public class POJO {
  @JsonCreator // can also be used for static factory methods
  public POJO(@JacksonInject DepartmentRepository repo, @JsonProperty("value") int value) {
      ....
  }
}
```

This might be enough to do what you are asking.

Comment: I've just tried to use @JacksonInject in the deserializer constructor but it does not works. It seems it only works for the classes that are going to be deserialized.

Comment: Correct, it is not meant to work for deserializers, as deserializers are never instantiated by Jackson (registration is with deserializer instances, not class). But is this a problem? You can inject this in constructor/factory method of the deserializer class, which is where you can use it as needed? Or is just used by deserializer to find something else that is passed to constructor?

Comment: As far as I know deserializer are instantiated by Jackson when you don't register them in the object mapper. When you just use @JsonDeserializer(contentUsing=MyCustomDeserializer.class) instantiation is done by Jackson.

Comment: Ah, yes, forgot that part, you are right. Interesting -- there could be a feature request for injection there. One problem, however, is that deserializers are instantiated once, cached; even contextual ones.

Comment: Mmmm that is strange. Because I'm devoloping a web service with a REST API using Jersey + Google Guice and every time a hit a method that has to deserialize a department a new deserializer gets created. I'm currently resolving this issue by using an static helper class that provides the repositories. This repositories are injected using guice. But this is not the best solution. On the other side I need the deserializer to be created on every request because the repositories depend on the entity manager and when you use guice a new EM gets created for every request.

Comment: Deserializers are cached by ObjectMapper, so creation of new ones could occur if mappers are not reused (and this has major performance downsides). Another possibility: Jackson value injection works via DeserializationContext, so deserializer could access injectable values easily -- this would allow passing things you need, if you can call ObjectMapper directly; injectable values can be (and are expected to be) reset for each request.

Comment: Hi StaxMan, can you please give an example of how to use injectable value in the DeserializationContext so that it can be used by a custom deserializer?

Comment: @Skylark alas, injectable values are injected in value being deserialized, and only with default POJO deser, so not necessarily accessible to custom deserializer. Attributes, on the other hand, set/gettable via context (DeserializationContext.getAttribute(...)).

Answer (score 2):

You can add a custom serializer/deserializer with a non-default constructor by registering it as a module with you `ObjectMapper`.

```
SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
JsonDeserializer<MyObject> customDeserializer = new CustomDeserializer("Blah");
simpleModule.addDeserializer(MyObject.class, customDeserializer);
mapper.registerModule(simpleModule);
```

You should also remove the annotation in the `MyObject` class if it's there.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a deserializer I just wrote. Note the use of a non-default constructor.

```
public class SparseStringArrayVectorDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<SparseStringArrayVector> {

@Override
public SparseStringArrayVector deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {

    /* This isn't the most efficient way to do this, since we're building a tree of nodes that we will discard.
     * However, we need to change the order around, so something like this is hard to avoid.
     */
    JsonNode tree = jp.readValueAsTree();
    int tokenCount = tree.size();
    int[] indexes = new int[tokenCount];
    String[][] strings = new String[tokenCount][];
    Iterator<Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldNameIt = tree.getFields();
    int slot = 0;
    while (fieldNameIt.hasNext()) {
        Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = fieldNameIt.next();
        int index = Integer.parseInt(entry.getKey());
        indexes[slot] = index;
        String[] thisTokenStrings = new String[entry.getValue().size()];
        for (int x = 0; x < thisTokenStrings.length; x++) {
            thisTokenStrings[x] = entry.getValue().get(x).getTextValue();
        }
        strings[slot] = thisTokenStrings;
        slot++;
    }
    return new SparseStringArrayVector(indexes, strings);
}
}
```

Used with the following. Note that you could have any constructor pattern that you like when creating the deserializer and adding it to the module.

```
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("ResultAccess", new Version(7, 4, 0, null));
    module.addDeserializer(SparseStringArrayVector.class, new SparseStringArrayVectorDeserializer());
    module.addDeserializer(AbstractResultAccess.class, new ProxyAbstractResultAccessDeserializer());
    mapper.registerModule(module);
```

Comment: The non-default constructor is for the deserializer, not for the class that is being deserialized

Comment: "tree.getFields()" should be "tree.fields()", as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

No, at the very beginning, you can go without specify a custom deserializer; Jackson can detect your nested field and map them correctly, *only when all the model classes implements `Serializable`*.

So, add `implements Serializable` to `Department` and `Person`, and you will see Jackson works out of the box.

Answer (score -2):

Just off the top of my head, I am pretty sure you can do that using the annotations in Jackson to identify which properties you want to exposure.